# pulling date from mysql returns all days in the future

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to figure out how to only pull reminders for the current week, any advice would be appreciated.

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE reminder >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) ORDER BY firstname") or die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());
```

Comment: In the other question there are PHP functions used. No duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

Very naive approach:
`WHERE YEARWEEK(reminder) = YEARWEEK(NOW())`. It works, but it won't use an index on `reminder` (I believe there is an index). Also, `YEARWEEK` will be executed for each record. The right way is to use query like `WHERE reminder >=[start_date] and reminder <= [end_date]` (or `reminder BETWEEN [start_date] AND [end_date]`) where [start_date] and [end_date] represent the first and last day of the current week respectively. I think it's easier to calculate these dates on client side, but it's also possible to write a function on mysql that returns desired date.

Comment: He should just get the two dates in his PHP code and put them in the query. That'll allow MySQL to use an index on the date column, where since your solution uses a function, it can't. Since this is the only column he's filtering by, that's a terribad thing.

Comment: @Dan Grossman: I agree, it's much better to calculate start/end dates in advance